# How do I add a vector as a row to an existing data frame when the vector is longer than the data frame

Tags: r

Apologies for a probably basic question but I can't seem to work out how to get this to work...

I want to add a row vector to an existing data frame. However, often the new row will have more columns than the existing data frame and I would like to fill the missing column entries with NA or blank strings.

For example, using this set up:

```
existing <- data.frame(rbind(letters[1:5], letters[6:10]))
new_row <- letters[20:26]
```

I would like to end up with the following:

```
a  b  c  d  e  ""  ""
f  g  h  i  j  ""  ""
t  u  v  w  x  y   z
```

The rbind function only accept equal width vectors. I have heard of rbind.fill from the plyr package but this only works for two data frames. Does anyone have a simple way to do this?

Many thanks
Adrian

Comment: Quick question, sorry to be slightly off topic: are you doing this inside a for loop (as in, adding rows one at a time to a data frame?) If so, it would be much faster to construct them as a list then use `dplyr::bind_rows`.

Comment: As for your question, once you've ensured the column names are consistent between `existing` and `new_row` you could do `dplyr::bind_rows(existing, as.data.frame(t(new_row)))`

Comment: David - yes that is exactly what I want to do. I have not looked at dplyr, I shall investigate. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `lapply` to create a list of the data frames you want to combine. Make sure their column names are consistent, since that's how they're combined. If you get stuck you could edit the question and ping me

Comment: Hi David, could you elaborate a bit further on using bind_rows on a list, do you mean turn each vector into a one row data frame and then create a list of these data frames to use in row_bind? - sorry only just noticed you last comment. ta!